# How does python order values in a heap?

Tags: python, python-2.7, heap

For example, a list of random numbers:

```
>>> x = [1,24,5,1,5,1,23,6]
>>> heapq.heapify(x)
[1, 1, 1, 6, 5, 5, 23, 24]
```

Why does it arbitrarily do 6,5,5 and not 5,5,6 or 5,6,5?

Answer (score 3):

Python docs contain following description of [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#module-heapq):

> Heaps are binary trees for which every parent node has a value less than or equal to any of its children. This implementation uses arrays for which `heap[k] <= heap[2*k+1]` and `heap[k] <= heap[2*k+2]` for all `k`, counting elements from zero. For the sake of comparison, non-existing elements are considered to be infinite. The interesting property of a heap is that its smallest element is always the root, `heap[0]`.

You can verify this with your example data:

```
>>> for i in xrange(len(x)):
...     print '{0} <= {1}'.format(x[i], x[i*2+1:i*2+3])
...
1 <= [1, 1]
1 <= [6, 5]
1 <= [5, 23]
6 <= [24]
5 <= []
5 <= []
23 <= []
24 <= []
```

For more information about binary heaps you can check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap).